# How to create a "subtraction matrix"? -python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am a novice programmer.

I would like to create a "subtraction matrix." (I lack the vocabulary to describe it). I would like to create a matrix from all the combination of subtractions.

```
v = [1, 5, 10]

0   4   9
4   0   5
9   5   0
```

I think I am missing something very basic with `numpy` but I do know what it is.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize *numpy* broadcasting:

```
v = np.array([1, 5, 10])

# v[:, None] creates a 2d array, when subtracted by a 1d array, the broadcasting rule will
# make a cartesian subtraction 
np.abs(v[:, None] - v)

#array([[0, 4, 9],
#       [4, 0, 5],
#       [9, 5, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch you guys!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `outer` method of the `subtract` ufunc. `outer` applies the operation (in this case subtraction) to every possible pair and arranges the result in a matrix:

```
v = [1, 5, 10]
np.absolute(np.subtract.outer(v, v))
# array([[0, 4, 9],
#        [4, 0, 5],
#        [9, 5, 0]])
```

Conveniently, it accepts lists etc. without you having to explicitly cast them to array.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `numpy`, you could use nested `for` loops:

```
v = [1, 5, 10]
vLen = len(v)
subMatrix = [[0]*vLen for x in range(vLen)] //creates empty matrix
for i in range(vLen):
    for j in range(vLen):
        subMatrix[j][i] = abs(v[i] - v[j])
# [[0, 4, 9],
#  [4, 0, 5],
#  [9, 5, 0]]
```

Edit: @aryamccarthy pointed out that `for` loops are less efficient than `numpy` broadcasting. Another alternative that he gave would be to use list comprehension for the same result:

```
v = [1, 5, 10]
subMatrix = [[abs(i - j) for i in v] for j in v]
```

Comment: By comparison to `numpy` broadcasting, this is terribly inefficient. Python's `for`-loops are super slow. Further, the asker only shows non-negative values in the intended output.

Comment: Good point, @aryamccarthy. I updated my answer to mention this and to only return positive values. I just wanted to show another perspective that shows how the task could be accomplished without third party packages.

Comment: Have you thought of expressing this as a list comprehension? 
`[[abs(i - j) for i in v] for j in v]`

Comment: Once again, you're right. That works much better. Maybe I should leave the answering to the pros until I get more python experience.

Comment: No, you're making positive contributions. This is how you learn, too—not just the asker. SO is a community; this answer was crafted by a community and started with you.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you, Arya!